# how to make a clone of root user

Tags: linux, unix, root

how to create a clone of **root** user in linux. 
means.
consider i am the **root** and I want to add **new_user** and grant that **new_user** to have all the root access/permission, 
how can I do that ?

Comment: add the user to superuser group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can usually get away with just adding a new user with *any* UID, and then change `/etc/passwd` to set the UID of it to 0.

This doesn't actually clone all the user information and files, it just gives you another user equivalent to root. That may be enough depending on your needs.

If you want a *real* user totally distinct from `root` yet able to do all root-y things, your best bet is to simply set up one with the appropriate `sudo` powers.